# Android Expand JNI Local Reference Table

Tags: java, android, c++, memory, java-native-interface

I have a lot of objects to create on c++ and send it to java, I'm using the `env->DeleteLocalRef(obj);` but I'm getting the following error:

```
06-10 18:43:56.976: E/dalvikvm(11536): JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536): JNI local reference table (0x4d9c0b28) dump:
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):   Last 10 entries (of 512):
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       511: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       510: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       509: 0x40e2a2a8 la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint[] (20 elements)
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       508: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       507: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       506: 0x412de350 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.BikeRoute>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       505: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       504: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       503: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       502: 0x412bab68 java.lang.Class<la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint>
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):   Summary:
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):       505 of java.lang.Class (7 unique instances)
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):         3 of java.lang.String (3 unique instances)
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):         1 of java.lang.String[] (2 elements)
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):         1 of la.jurema.moovebike.network.DataDownloadResponseAbstract
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):         1 of la.jurema.moovebike.models.BikeRoute[] (15 elements)
06-10 18:43:56.980: W/dalvikvm(11536):         1 of la.jurema.moovebike.models.RoutePoint[] (20 elements)
06-10 18:43:56.980: E/dalvikvm(11536): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
```

I dont know what means this `java.lang.Class`... how I can solve this? Increase the reference table? Or what I'm not deleting?

Comment: It means you have more references in the current frame than will fit.  You can call `(*env)->PushLocalFrame(env, N)` to allocate more space before calling the code that actually generates the references.  You should try to free local references whenever you are able as well.

Comment: @technomage I'm freeing all local reference as possible, but i really have a lot of instances.... how i can use PushLocalFrame? for example to use 1024 also 512 of memory?

Comment: Surround your "allocating" code with `PushLocalFrame(env, 2048)` and `PopLocalFrame(env)`, then you won't have to delete individual references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to delete local references to classes as well as to objects.

Comment: you said "jclass" references? how I do it?

Comment: Same as for objects, with DeleteLocalRef(). A jclass actually is-a jobject.

Comment: If your patterns are repetive you should also have a look at `PushLocalFrame()` and `PopLocalFrame()`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're getting lots of instances of `java.lang.Class`.  The most common way to get these is by calling `FindClass`.  The name in the <> angle brackets is the name of the class that was looked up, so you should be looking for places where you do a lookup on `RoutePoint` or `BikeRoute`.

`FindClass` can be fairly expensive, so for frequently-used classes you want to call that during initialization and cache the result (as a global reference) for later use.

If you're running in a loop, it's a good idea to explicitly delete the local reference for any object returned.  Expanding the local reference table beyond 512 entries isn't possible in Dalvik.

See also the [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) document.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following technique useful if not horribly verbose, I created a class called Guardian as follows:

```
/*
 * Guardian.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 14, 2014
 *      Author: yaturner
 */
#ifndef GUARDIAN_H_
#define GUARDIAN_H_

#define GLOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, tagName, __VA_ARGS__ )

{

class Guardian
{
private:
    char* funcName;
    char* tagName;

public:
    Guardian(const char*, const char*);
    virtual ~Guardian();
};

#endif /* GUARDIAN_H_ */
```

and

```
/*
 * Guardian.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 14, 2014
 *      Author: yaturner
 */
#include "Guardian.h"

Guardian(const char* func, const char* tag)
{
    int len = strlen(func);
    funcName = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(funcName, func);
    len = strlen(func);
    tagName = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(tagName, tag);
    GLOGD("Entering %s", funcName);
}

~Guardian()
{
    GLOGD("Exiting %s", funcName);
    dumpLocalRefTable();
    free(funcName);
    free(tagName);

}
```

and

```
void dumpLocalRefTable()
{
    JNIEnv* env = preamble(); 
    jclass vm_class = env->FindClass("dalvik/system/VMDebug");
    jmethodID dump_mid = env->GetStaticMethodID( vm_class, "dumpReferenceTables", "()V" );
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod( vm_class, dump_mid );

    env->DeleteLocalRef(vm_class);
}
```

Then at the beginning of each of my JNI methods I instanciated the Guardian class, what I got was a massive logcat with each method entry and exit plus the ref table. By examining the log I could look for changes in the table and determine what method caused them. Painful but it worked.