# Android app crashes due to large number of images

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that will require about 520 small png's. I've stored these in my assets folder and I access them using getAssets().

However my app crashes at startup and works OK if I reduce the number of images in the folder. Is it possible to store additional images somewhere else or to increase the size of images that my app can handle?

My logcat error is "Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)"

each image is about 4kb large, the total folder size is 2.1 Mb

The relevant code is:

```
        AssetManager assets = getAssets();
    fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    fileNameList.clear();

    String[] paths;
    try {
        paths = assets.list("final");

        for (String path : paths)
            fileNameList.add(path.replace(".jpg", ""));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image file names", e);
    } // end catch
```

Comment: How small - i.e. file size - are the pngs? Also is this crashing because of an OutOfMemory error? and how are they being displayed (e.g. listview, imageview, gridview)? You probably need to reduce the file size by using lower resolution images to make this work.

Comment: Can you also post your code where you're retrieving the images. You could be potentially doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @btse: The code works with a handful of images. I've posted a snippet above

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033438/android-expand-jni-local-reference-table). You cannot expand the reference table beyond 512 items so you need to delete local references to class and/or objects to free up space.

Comment: I have reduced the no. of images to 460. No change, and also, I can't figure why I get a JNI error yet I havent used JNI in my code

Comment: Well then that makes no sense.